# Add static ARP entries on boot [systemd]

Tags: networking, systemd, raspbian, arp

I wanted to add a number of static ARP entries that will persist across system reboots. For that I tried using a systemd service which would simply populate the ARP table via the `/etc/ethers` file:

```
[Unit]
Description=startup-test
After=network-online.target
Wants=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=root
Group=root
ExecStart=arp -f
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This method does not work and the ARP entries are not added on boot, but the systemd service appears to run the `arp -f` command (though unsuccessfully because the "network is unreachable"):

Output of `systemctl status`:

```
● startup.service - startup-test
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/startup.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead) since Sun 2023-01-29 15:10:53 EET; 1min 7s ago
    Process: 562 ExecStart=arp -f (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 562 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
        CPU: 14ms

Jan 29 15:10:52 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started startup-test.
Jan 29 15:10:53 raspberrypi arp[562]: SIOCSARP: Network is unreachable
Jan 29 15:10:53 raspberrypi arp[562]: arp: cannot set entry on line 1 of etherfile /etc/ethers !
Jan 29 15:10:53 raspberrypi arp[562]: SIOCSARP: Network is unreachable
Jan 29 15:10:53 raspberrypi arp[562]: arp: cannot set entry on line 2 of etherfile /etc/ethers !
Jan 29 15:10:53 raspberrypi systemd[1]: startup.service: Succeeded.
```

If however I manually start the service with `systemctl start`, no errors are thrown (and the ARP table is populated as expected).

Output of `systemctl status` after starting it manually:

```
● startup.service - startup-test
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/startup.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead) since Sun 2023-01-29 15:11:55 EET; 5s ago
    Process: 1664 ExecStart=arp -f (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 1664 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
        CPU: 13ms

Jan 29 15:11:55 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started startup-test.
Jan 29 15:11:55 raspberrypi systemd[1]: startup.service: Succeeded.
```

What is wrong here?

PS. I've managed to do what I want by using `dhcpcd` hooks. So I'm not looking for an alternative method, I just would like to know what is wrong with the systemd approach.

(Raspbian Bullseye)

Comment: You can try adding an explicit wait for a given interface, eg eth1: `ExecStartPre=/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-networkd-wait-online -i=eth1`